# Fourier transform of f on the unit sphere

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

My question is: do we have the right to compute the fourier transform of a function over the unit sphere? To be more precise, let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R} ^n)$, $n\geq1$. Is the integral
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}f(t)e^{-i\langle \omega|t\rangle} d\sigma(t), $$
make any sense? With of course $S^{n-1}$ denotes the unit sphere and $d\sigma$ is the measure over the sphere.

Comment: You have the right to do anything you want. The question is whether it has some utility. There are constructions like this that are useful. Read about the Radon transform, and read about Harmonic analysis on Lie groups. Without some explanation of why you are interested, any answer would just be a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I'm interested in harmonic analysis and uncertainty principles associated to many operator integrals

Comment: @CharlieFrohman: I totally agree with the incipit of your comment. That is why I deeply dislike the use of the adjective "legit" in mathematics.

Comment: The keyword to search for is "Restriction problem for the Fourier transform". Here's a Terry Tao blog post on the subject: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/the-bourgain-guth-argument-for-proving-restriction-theorems/

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense as is. An element of $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not a function. It is an equivalence class of functions modulo equality away from (Lebesgue) measure zero sets. The sphere $S^{n-1}$ has measure zero, so it does not make sense to evaluate your $f$ on it. You need some regularity hypothesis on $f$, e.g., being continuous or being in a Sobolev space with a trace theorem to $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: $S^{n-1}$ has non-zero Lebesgue measure...

Comment: @Monku: the measure I am talking about is not the measure $d\sigma$ on the sphere but the Lebesgue measure $d\lambda$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which contains the sphere. The latter has measure zero $\lambda(S^{n-1})=0$. For example for $n=2$, it just means the unit circle has zero area.